# How to run pypy with an existing installation of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypy

I am trying to run my code written in Python 3 with pypy, but I got an error :

> ImportError: No module named 'osgeo'

but running it with `python3 test.py` works (but slow) .

My installed version of python is 3.5.2 
pypy comes with it's python version 3.5.3

Is there anyway you could tell pypy to use my own version of python, and will it resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PyPy3?

If you use PyPy it will execute your code with a Python 2.7 interpreter. And if you install a library for python3 it does not mean that the library is installed for python2 too. You need to specify for wich interpreter are you installing the library ( like using pip or pip3 )

Comment: It's unrelated to PyPy2 versus PyPy3.  The problem is only that you need to install anything you want to use with PyPy, whatever the version, because it won't pick up what is installed for CPython.  It's two different interpreters, in the same way that CPython 3.4 and CPython 3.5 are different interpreters: you need to install packages for each one.

Comment: for Carlos Lucas , i'm using pypy3

Comment: Armin , how can i install the gdal librarie for pypy3 !
cuz i kinda installed it first with apt-get like this :

sudo apt install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal